# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this basic code:

Html:

```
<form name='susprip' action='susprip.php'>
    <strong>Annually:</strong> <input type='text' name='user' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='pass' value=''>
    <input type='text' name='mail' value=''>
    <input type='radio' name='wtd' value='Suspend'>Suspend<input type='radio' name='wtd' value='Unsuspend'>Unsuspend<input type='radio' name='wtd' value='Create'>Create
    <a href='javascript: submitform()'>Submit</a>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["susprip"].submit();
}
```

It was all working fine and now when I try to click the submit link, nothing happens. I get this in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined susprip.js:3
submitform susprip.js:3
(anonymous function)
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance :)

Comment: And you probably included the script before the element in the DOM.

Comment: Oh, and use the `onclick` handler if you can't attach proper event handlers, at least it works.

Comment: I have another form which is exactly the same with different names and that works absolutely fine. I am confused :S

Comment: @adeneo onclick handler gives:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined 
submitform
onclick`

Comment: You should be doing something more like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/zT9T4/1/

Comment: Now I dont see any error but when I click Submit, nothing happens. See this http://jsfiddle.net/zT9T4/4/ Here, both forms are working fine but in my code the first one is not working while the second one is working fine.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have declared the method for the form to use

Comment: They both submit when you click the anchor, what are you expecting ?